# REST filter based on ACF properties does not work

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I have this REST data:

```
[{"id":215,"acf":{"stad":{"value":"barcelona","label":"barcelona"},"description":"","images":[{"ID":191,"id":191,"title":"logo-black.png","filename":"logo-black.png","filesize":3080,"url":"https:\/\/wordpress-132670-574369.cloudwaysapps.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/logo-black.png","link":"https:\/\/wordpress-132670-574369.cloudwaysapps.com\/logo-black-png\/","alt":"","author":"1","description":"","caption":"","name":"logo-black-png","status":"inherit","uploaded_to":0,"date":"2018-04-16 15:39:37","modified":"2018-08-05 15:19:12","menu_order":0,"mime_type":"image\/png","type":"image","subtype":"png","icon":"https:\/\/wordpress-132670-574369.cloudwaysapps.com\/wp-includes\/images\/media\/default.png","width":443,"height":98,"sizes":{"thumbnail":"https:\/\/wordpress-132670-574369.cloudwaysapps.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/logo-black-150x98.png","thumbnail-width":150,"thumbnail-height":98,"medium":"https:\/\/wordpress-132670-574369.cloudwaysapps.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/logo-black-300x66.png","medium-width":300,"medium-height":66,"medium_large":"https:\/\/wordpress-132670-574369.cloudwaysapps.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/logo-black.png","medium_large-width":443,"medium_large-height":98,"large":"https:\/\/wordpress-132670-574369.cloudwaysapps.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/logo-black.png","large-width":443,"large-height":98}}]}},{"id":205,"acf":{"stad":{"value":"oslo","label":"oslo"},"description":"","images":false,"myid":"333"}}]
```

I created a filter to query with the "myid" parameter like this:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/hotels/?myid=333
```

This is the filter code I added to the **functions.php**:

```
add_filter('rest_hotels_vars', function ($valid_vars)
{
    return array_merge($valid_vars, array('myid', 'meta_query'));
});


add_filter('rest_hotels_query', function($args, $request) 
{
    $myid = $request->get_param('myid');

    if (!empty( $myid)) 
    {
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'myid',
                'value'   => $myid,
                'compare' => '=',
            )
        );      
    }

    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Hotels is a custom post type.

The query always returns all the rows, the filter has no effect.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the filter closely you will understand the error.

apply_filters( "rest_{$this->post_type}_query", array $args, WP_REST_Request $request );

This is your code:

```
add_filter('rest_hotels_query', function($args, $request){

$myid = $request->get_param('myid');

if (!empty( $myid)) 
{
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'myid',
            'value'   => $myid,
            'compare' => '=',
        )
    );      
}

return $args;

}, 10, 2 );
```

Here rest_hotels_query : we need to put post type name please be careful, if your post type name is hotel then filter should be like : "rest_hotel_query"

This is the working code:

```
add_filter('rest_hotel_query', function($args, $request){
$myid = $request->get_param('myid');

if (!empty( $myid)) 
{
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'myid',
            'value'   => $myid,
            'compare' => '=',
        )
    );      
}

return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Same case with the collection parameters for the posts controller:

apply_filters( "rest_{$this->post_type}_query", array $args, WP_REST_Request $request );

It should be :

```
   add_filter('rest_hotel_collection_params', function ($valid_vars){
    return array_merge($valid_vars, array('myid', 'meta_query'));
   });
```

Comment: well, that's exactly what I said in my reply and more (and I tested and got it working in my environment), and the OP says it didn't work. But you must have magic powers since they accepted this answer. Something smells fishy.

Answer (score 0):

The `rest_query_vars` filter no longer exists. Take a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_collection_params/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/

So replace this

```
add_filter('rest_hotels_vars', function ($valid_vars)
{
   return array_merge($valid_vars, array('myid', 'meta_query'));
});
```

with this

```
add_filter('rest_hotels_collection_params', function ($valid_vars)
{
   return array_merge($valid_vars, array('myid', 'meta_query'));
});
```

and it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. "Hotels" is a custom post type and "myid" is an ACF field. Does the code need to handle that in some way?